# How to style div.div inline?

Tags: css, inline-code

How would I style this CSS class inline?

```
.myClass div{
display:block;
position:absolute;
}
```

I have already tried:

```
<div class="myClass" style="div {display:block; position:absolute;}"></div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="myClass" style="display:block; position:absolute;"></div>
```

But from what it seems like.. you are asking how to style the child div

in that case...

```
<div class="myClass">
    <div style="display:block; position:absolute;"></div>
</div>
```